# Play framework reverse routing with static parameters

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

Cant fix the following Problem:

Im trying to generate a URL with reverse-routing:

```
Router.reverse(action).url
```

of this route:

```
GET /admin/productgroups ProductGroupController.renderListView(modelClass:'models.ProductGroup')
```

I've tried the following:

```
Router.reverse("ProductGroupController.renderListView").url
Router.reverse("ProductGroupController.renderListView(modelClass:'models.ProductGroup'").url
```

But im getting always a

```
No route found

No route able to invoke action views.ProductGrouController.renderListView() with arguments {} was found.
```

Exception... Need some help, dunno what im doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to pass the modelClass name as string argument inside a map like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("modelClass", "models.ProductGroup");

Router.reverse("ProductGroupController.renderListView", map).url
```

This must always be done when you are passing static parameters to your routes file.